# How to remove app from early access on google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I published an open testing release of my app on google play store. The app is shown as "App name (Early Access)". Then I published a new version to production. However on my android device I still see it as early access. I tried to uninstall it but it won't change. Although the version that is installed is the one from production. The problem is cannot give it a review. Any idea on how to get rid of this early access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with a clear cache & data for Google Play Store app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to 'Manage Country Availability' and uncheck everything.
There may be an easier way to do it, but this should work.